# VAE training: loss function reducing to nan

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am training a VAE to on a black and white Cat images dataset.

Dataset link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SoXCBAdVQmRUzLwZ9508SkfKtAYEdzVW?usp=share_link

The notebook link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W7bMPqHy2sSmPVUJh9dtr2AwHEeuHuti/view?usp=share_link

The issue: The total loss and the KL loss becomes nan.

I have checked for the following things.

1. The normalization is with respect to the max pixel intensity which is 255. So all the pixel values are between [0,1] which is suitable for the sigmoid activation function.
2. Learning rate is 0.0001 which is substantially less from the 0.0005.
3. Checked the input data no NaNs
4. Tried to multiply a range of numbers to bring the KL loss down. I have tried 0.00001, 0.0001,0.001 and 0.01

**Sharing the loss function for reference:**

```
def _calculate_reconstruction_loss(y_target, y_predicted):
    error = y_target - y_predicted
    reconstruction_loss = K.mean(K.square(error), axis=[1, 2, 3])
    return reconstruction_loss


def calculate_kl_loss(model):
    # wrap `_calculate_kl_loss` such that it takes the model as an argument,
    # returns a function which can take arbitrary number of arguments
    # (for compatibility with `metrics` and utility in the loss function)
    # and returns the kl loss
    def _calculate_kl_loss(*args):
        kl_loss = -0.5 * K.mean(1 + model.log_variance*0.01 - K.square(model.mu) - K.exp(model.log_variance*0.01), axis=1)
        return kl_loss
    return _calculate_kl_loss
```

Looking for suggestions to solve the NaN problem.